# how I can synchronized the airflow dags repository in github with an azure storage account?

Tags: azure, github, kubernetes, airflow, azure-aks

it's possible to synchronize repo github for dags with an azure storage account?
I want that evey time i put the dags in github repository it appears on azure file share.

Answer (score 3):

***Airflow will not create the shared filesystem if you specify a Git repository. Instead, it will clone the DAG files to each of the nodes, and sync them periodically with the remote repository.***

You can refer this [*Document*](https://docs.bitnami.com/azure-templates/infrastructure/apache-airflow/configuration/sync-dags/) to Synchronize DAGs With A Remote Git Repository. Also do refer this [*Document*](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-devops-copy-files-from-git-repository-to-azure-storage-account/) that will help you to Copy Files From Git Repository To Azure Storage Account using Azure Devops